# Executing local python script on remote server(which has no python installed)

Tags: python, paramiko

I have 2 servers i.e local and remote server but the remote server has no python installed in it.Both servers have windows installed in it. I want to execute a local python script on remote server without installing python on remote server. For example I have local python script 'zip.py':

```
filenames = ['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('files.zip', mode='w')
for fname in filenames:
    zf.write(fname)
zf.close()
print
```

Another script to connect to remote server and execute 'zip.py' on remote server:

rem.py

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('15.111.109.123', username='ABC', password='123')
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(local_path,remote_path)   #to transfer zip.py from local to remote
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("zip.py")
```

But the local python script is not getting executed on remote server. How exactly to make it execute on remote server?? I want do execute using  script itself,not by installing cygwin and then doing ssh to the server.

Comment: creating executable or Py2Exe could help : https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script

Comment: Executing scripts which need an rutime intepreter is not possible. You have to install it on the server or ship it with your script, see comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your looking for a portable executable (a program that doesn't need to be installed to run). Here are some python ones:

1. [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io):
   *"The easiest way to run Python, Spyder with SciPy and friends out of the box on any Windows PC, without installing anything!"*
2. [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)